# How can I share realtime Google Analytics data with others?

Tags: google-analytics, visualization, data-visualization, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I've been trying to share only Realtime Google Analytics data with all my team members. I know I can create a custom dashboard and share it with them, but it also gives them access to all the data.

1. Is there a way I can restrict/share ONLY the realtime stats?
2. Any third party visualization tool?

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: [embeddedanalytics.com](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com)  (*disclosure: I work with them*).

We have many different [self-serve widgets](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/embeddedanalytics-realtime-reporting.html) available plus can customize to your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You could just send it to them with the "Email" functionality. The only downside here is that they can't hover and see details about data points and stuff - it's basically just a PDF picture of the dashboard.

Just create a dashboard. Press "Email" at the top. Here, you can schedule it to send regularly (ie: every Monday or once a month). GA will send them a PDF with the static dashboard.

If you ever want to change the email frequency/refresh it, just go to Admin > View > Scheduled Emails. They expire after a year, I think.